# FFT doesn't seem to return correct results

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

I have performed an FFT on my data and quite frankly it doesn't look right. The signal is a mix of heartbeat and muscle tremor and I was hoping to separate the two. The data (sampled at 0.002s) can be found on https://pastebin.com/Ld2YUny2

Am I doing something incorrectly here? The FFT looks blocky.

The code that I found on this site :-) is:

```
    #FFT
    N = data4.size # number data points
    T = 1.0 / 500.0 # inverse of sampling rate
    x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N)
    y = data4
    yf = np.abs(scipy.fft(y))
    xf = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(data4.size, T)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(np.abs(xf), np.abs(yf))
    ax.set(xlim=(0, 5))
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the `ax.set(xlim=(0, 5))`, and you'll see more of your FFT. You're looking only at the first few samples.

Comment: Also, don't plot `np.abs(xf)`, `xf` is real-valued, you'll need to see those negative numbers.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the suggestions. The whole FFT contains a couple of interesting, well defined, spikes at 100Hz and 200Hz (which I will need to think about) - but my data contains a strong heartbeat (see the 5 pulses in roughly 5 seconds?) so I was kind of expecting a well defined spike around 1Hz and wondered if I'd implemented something incorrectly. With regards to the negative numbers I'm not yet looking to do an inverse transform.

Comment: No, I think you're doing it right. Except for the `abs(xf)` part, which will do weird things with your plot. Do `ax.plot(xf, np.abs(yf))`.

Comment: I have tried all sorts of combinations but I do not get the results I am expecting (or rather, hoping for). Maybe because each component of the heartbeat (PQRS) repeats at almost exactly the same freq it contributes to the noise around the peak I was hoping to see for the R part of the beat? Who knows? Looking around on the web there isn't much. At least you have reassured me that I am implementing the FFT correctly: Thanks!

Comment: Try using a [window function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) over your data to get a better definition in your peaks. Note how your signal length is not an integer multiple of the period of the heart beat. This leads to the peak for that frequency to be spread out over many bins. The window function should improve that somewhat.

Comment: Slightly (!) out of my area of expertise but I'm going to have a crack at it! Thanks :-)